# Hibernate da erro ao ler coluna do banco (reverse engineering)

Tags: java, hibernate

Quando vou tentar fazer engenharia reversa com o Hibernate, ele, não consegue ler as colunas do bd. Da esse erro "Reading Schema Error: Erro while reading column meta data for curso"

Alguém faz ideia do que seja? Aparentemente ele está entrando no banco por estar dando o nome da coluna...

esse é meu hibernate.cfg

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cursojava</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">******</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

[image: Esse é o erro]

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Que ferramenta é esta? Não parece ser um erro do próprio hibernate mas sim da ferramenta que está usando

Comment: É o eclipse. Coloquei em perspectiva de hibernate e consegui ir mais a fundo no erro. 
O erro que causou isso é este:

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Comment: Recomendo então direcionar a pergunta para um problema no plugin do Eclipse, citando qual o nome deste plugin (se ele tem um, etc). Importante também colocar na sua pergunta este log que passou, pois pode ser algo relacionado diretamente ao PostgreSQL